# I am not able to print variable in my emotion.html

Tags: python, django

I am pretty newbie in python, and I am detecting emotion of music using spotify api, but when I am passing dictionary values to the html, It prints nothing. whereas I am able to print in commandline,

When I am writing {{ energy }}
It prints nothing when I access localhost:8000//emotion

This is my function in views.py

```
def emotion(request):
from mutagen.id3 import ID3
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import sys
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import requests
import spotify_token as st
import requests

client_id = '**********************'
client_secret = '*****************************'
title = 'lollypop'
artist = 'pawan singh'

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
sp.trace=False
search_query = title+ ' ' + artist
result = sp.search(search_query)
for i in result['tracks']['items']:
    # Find a songh that matches title and artist
    if (i['artists'][0]['name'] == artist) and (i['name'] == title):
        print (i['uri'])
        break
else:
    try:
        # Just take the first song returned by the search (might be named differently)
        print (result['tracks']['items'][0]['uri'])
        uri = result['tracks']['items'][0]['uri']
        client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
        sp.trace=False
        features = sp.audio_features(uri)

        data = {
            'energy' : features[0]['energy'],
            'key' : features[0]['key'],
            'valence': features[0]['valence'],
            'danceability': features[0]['danceability'],
            'loundness' : features[0]['loudness'],
            'tempo' : round(features[0]['tempo']),
            'acousticness' : features[0]['acousticness'],
            'liveness' : features[0]['liveness'],
            'instrumentalness' : features[0]['instrumentalness'],
        }

        print(features[0]['energy'])  # Prints successfully 0.862
        
    except:
        data = { 'error' : 'NO SONGS FOUND' }
return render(request, 'emotion_view.html', data)
```

This is my emotion_view.html in templates

```py
{{ energy }}
```

And in emotion_view.html, It prints nothing, what is wrong with it

Comment: Your whole template code is just `{{ energy }}` or do you have more code? Are you able to print anything else in that template? Is it hardcoded or is it a context variable as well?

Comment: @Abhishek Vishwakarma show you emotion_view.html code lines where you try to print out data. This else: is outside if block? Possible case is that you html call don't get output from else block.

Comment: Just out of curiosity would `{{energy}}` even do anything since the only reference to it is inside the `data` dictionary?

Comment: Actually I am not able to print the variables in any html file. I don't know why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Change `{{energy}}` to `{{error}}` in your  `emotion_view.html`, as you are passing `'error'` in your data dictionary and not `'energy'`